# Проверить, является ли строка IP-адресом

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, ip-address

Кто-нибудь подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить следующую задачу:
IP-адрес

В сети интернет каждому компьютеру присваивается четырехбайтовый код, который принято записывать в виде четырех чисел, каждое из которых может принимать значения от 0 до 255, разделенных точками. Вот примеры правильных IP-адресов:

127.0.0.0

192.168.0.1

255.0.255.255

Программа получает на вход строку из произвольных символов. Если эта строка является корректной записью IP-адреса, выведите YES, иначе выведите NO.

Comment: Не хватает ограничений по инструментам или хотя бы по языкам. Способов - мульон и маленькая тележка...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Вариант 1. Разбить по точке на 4 подстроки, преобразовать каждую в число, убедиться, что число лежит в диапазоне.
- Вариант 2. [Не]сложное регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте

```
in_addr_t inet_addr(const char *cp);
```

`man 3 inet_addr`

Comment: Вот, удалил кто-то замечательное обсуждение, достаточно полно описывающее формы записи IP адреса. Попробую восстановить тут его итог.

--

IPv4 адрес это 32-битное число (4 байта) без знака, которое может быть записано одним из следующих способов:

    a       все 32 бита
    a.b     8.24 бита
    a.b.c   8.8.16 бит
    a.b.c.d все части по 8 бит

Каждое число (a,b,c,d) может быть (независимо от формата других) записано в десятичном, восьмеричном (0...) или 16-ричном (0x...) формате. Незначащие нули допустимы. Переполнение любой из частей (8,16,24 бит) не допускается.

Comment: да, уведомления об удалённых ответах пришли, а тут - ничего :(
но - что мы привязались-то к простому учебному заданию :) нагрузили подробностями, а всего-то, наверное, нужно было для начала объяснить что 1) ip это число 2) записывается в удобном для глаза формате, группами десятичных цифр (как на вкладке "свойства соединения в windows" 3) запись десятичного числа переводится из строки так-то и так-то. нет, разбушевались :)

Comment: @klopp, не понял 

    да, уведомления об удалённых ответах пришли, а тут - ничего 

О чем это Вы?

--

О "разбушевались". А дело тут ведь не в конкретном учебном задании ТС. 

Некоторые вопросы в форуме просто открывают тему для обсуждения, которое и началось. В результате, я например, да, думаю и все остальные участники дискуссии, наконец-то (неожиданно) выяснили *какими способами можно* записывать IP.

Вот такое общение (с получением новых знаний) и является **самым главным** на этом форуме (чем он вообще ценен). Причем, "по заказу" ничего подобного не получается.

Такие, вот, дела.

Comment: >О чем это Вы?

О том, что вот к этому обсуждению, например, мне в почту пришло как минимум 5 уведомлений с разными мыслями :) которых не вижу на странице вообще (удалены? кем, зачем?)

Comment: @klopp, а, об этом!

Был тут ответ от @Barmaley. В комментариях к нему и развернулось основное обсуждение, прояснившее вопрос.

 Вы в нем тоже поучаствовали, например, с комментарием:

    Вот всё никак не могу понять, зачем привлекать какие-то программы...

Потом  этот ответ сам  @Barmaley удалил  (видимо что-то не понравилось), естественно, вместе со всеми комментариями (наверное переносить их куда-то еще и сортировать поленился).

Comment: Ых, не удалось про приоритеты RFC/исходников поговорить :)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 3, не заморачиваясь лишними проверками :)

```
print 'OK' if $ip eq 
join('.', unpack('C4', pack('N', unpack('N', pack('C4', split(/\./, $ip))))));
```

Или, в общем виде:

```
true if ip == int2ip( ip2int(ip) )
```

Comment: @klopp, не знаю, что это за язык, но как он воспримет вот это:

    0x8.8.010.0x00000008


нормальный ip или нет?

Comment: @avp, я не знаю зачем кто-то сделал мой комментарий ответом. Целью было продемонстрировать, что не обязательно заниматься подробной валидацией входного формата: при жёстко заданных правилах преобразования строки в int обратное преобразование всё покажет :)

Очевидно, что явные аргументы [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) не предполагают распознавание  каких-то хитростей кроме десятичной СС без "заполнителей", но это и не было задачей. Достаточно того, что IP вида "256.1.1.1", "1278.0.0.1", "127.abc" проверку не пройдут.

Comment: Это скорее был комментарий для @Ашурбаннипал. Пусть задумается, что такой адрес тоже valid (по крайней мере для программ, вызывающих inet_addr()).

Comment: Вот всё никак не могу понять, зачем привлекать какие-то программы, которые что-то понимают. В конце концов запись, например, 16-ричной СС как 0xNN - не более чем одна из условностей, которая статуса глобальной и обязательной для всех не имеет. С тем же успехом можно считать "плохой" программой и `ping`, потому что она не понимает запись `80h.1.1.1`, например.

Comment: @klopp, все общение между людьми (и программами) основано на условностях.

Просто `inet_addr()` это одна из них. Все нормальные программы должны использовать ее (или полнофункциональный аналог).

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то `inet_aton`, а не `inet_addr` :) А везде ли есть `inet_aton`?

Comment: Это две функции в [одном файле](http://www.gnu-darwin.org/shims/inet_addr.c) и `inet_addr` вызывает `inet_aton`.

IMHO в любой нормальной libc они есть.

Comment: Так то в libc. А в младших Windows, например, на прикладном уровне рекомендовано юзать [RtlIpv4StringToAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814458(v=vs.85).aspx), как оно там - не знаю...